# Is it possible to consistently and naturally define this subset of Hardy field?

Tags: asymptotics, germs

Consider [Hardy field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_field) $H$, the field of germs of functions at positive infinity.

Can we define $H_I\subset H$, such that it would have the following properties:

- $H_I$ is an [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain).
- For each germ $u\in H$ there exists and only one infinitesimally close to it germ $w\in H_I$
- All germs of polynomials belong to $H_I$

These properties are not enough to define $H_I$, so here is my question.

Can there be a naturally and simply defined operator on germs that for each germ $u\in H$ would return the infinitesimally close to it germ from $H_I$? For instance the germs $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(x+1)$ are infinitesimally close, so the operator should invariably return only one of these functions (or something else, infinitesimally close to them).

Can we define $H_I$ by some easily verifiable property?